# How to handle the interface with package in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

I am creating a simple uvm tb these days and I meet an issue with interface usage. Here is my code.

in the /my_proj/tb_uvm/intf/my_if.svh file: (interface definition)

```
interface my_if (
    input iCLK,
    input iRSTb,
    inout data
);
clocking monitor_cb @(posedge iCLK);
    input iRSTb;
    input data;
endclocking
modport monitor_mp(
    clocking monitor_cb
); 
endinterface : my_if
```

and I need to instance this interface in the /my_proj/tb_uvm/agent/my_driver.svh file :

```
class my_driver extends uvm_driver;
    `uvm_component_utils(my_driver)
    virtual my_if m_vif;
    ...
endclass
```

I tried to define a package file(named my_agt_pkg.sv) under /my_proj/tb_uvm/agent/ because there are several driver/monitor files in this directory including the my_driver.svh I mentioned above.

```
package my_agt_pkg;
    import uvm_pkg::*;

    `include "my_driver.svh"
    `include "../intf/my_if.svh"
     ....
endpackage
```

but I failed to compile because of below error. Could anyone kindly give me a help on this issue ?

Found 'interface' inside package before 'endpackage'. 'interface' inside   'package' is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message means what is says: *you are not allowed to declare an interface inside a package*.

A `virtual interface` is a peculiar concept. It behaves like a class variable, but an `interface` gets defined and instantiated like a module.

Just move your interface declaration outside the `package`

Comment: Hi Dave, If I want to instance this interface in the current sv file and this sv file is included in the package, how can I handle it ?  ( I mean how can I declare the interface outside the package ?)

Comment: I tried to exclude this my_if.svh in my_agt_pkg.sv file. and retry to compile but failed with below error:   Error-[SV-UIOT] Undefined interface or type
../agent/my_driver.svh, 10
my_if, "m_vif"
  The definition for the forward-referenced interface 'my_if' is
  missing or 'my_if' is the name of an undefined user type.

Comment: oh, It works if I move the include statement before the package definition. now this error is disappeared although next error is popped up. I will take a further look on my side.. anyway, thank you very much !